# Any good cocoa libraries that include both salt and IV AES Encryption?

Tags: cocoa, encryption, aes, salt, initialization-vector

I am just polishing up my encryption tool, but I noticed I am missing the salt, which is importnat in order to make the encryption more secure. I am using some built in cocoa methods, but they don't include either. I don't want to write this from scratch because it would be hard to get right. Are there any good cocoa libraries out there that include salt and IVs for AES Encryption?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Rob Napier has written such an implementation](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564).

For decryption, you'll have to write that yourself:

> I will leave the decrypt method as an exercise for the reader. It’s almost identical, and it’s a good idea to actually understand this code, not just copy it.

Comment: Oh yes, he gave me that link, I forgot about that. Thanks, I'll take another look.